# Symfony api-platform won't attach to event listener

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2, api-platform.com

api-platform.com's event won't attach to my listener. I tried several combination from their event matrix but it still won't trigger.

```
# services.yml
user_access_listener:
    class:      AppBundle\Event\Listener\UserAccessListener
    arguments: [ "@security.authorization_checker" ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.view, method: onKernelView }
```

Here is my listener class

namespace AppBundle\Event\Listener;

```
use UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class UserAccessListener
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationCheckerInterface
     */
    private $authorizationChecker;

    /**
     * @param AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker
     */
    public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;

    }

    /**
     * @param GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelView(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {

        echo "This should trigger";
        exit;

        $user = $event->getControllerResult();
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted(null, $user)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }
    }
}
```

[api-platform event reference](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events)

I was expecting "This should trigger" would appear when I hit `GET /projects/1` and `GET /projects`, but it is not triggering. Thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean with `This should trigger`? Is this a part of unit test?

Comment: The kernel view event only gets triggered when the controller does not return a response object.  Is that the case in your app?  And pulling user from the controller result?  Typically your would check authorization in a controller event listener.  Right before the controller itself is called.

Comment: @Confidence I added an `echo` and `exit;` on that part to see if it is being triggered.

Comment: @Cerad I don't have controller for `GET /projects/` I am using the CRUD operations from api-platform's bundle. I have a separate security voter for my controllers but that is no triggered by the api-platform CRUD operation that's why I need to listen to api-platform's event.

Comment: So I just checked your api-platform link.  I want some of whatever it is that they are smoking!  Try bin/console debug:event-dispatcher  kernel.view to see if your view listener is even being registered.

Comment: @Cerad API Platform is built on top of Symfony's event listener. It doesn't use the default controller system.

Answer (score 1):

Your should use a higher priority (70 for instance), to be sure that your listener is executed before the builtin view listeners.

Example:

```
user_access_listener:
    class:      AppBundle\Event\Listener\UserAccessListener
    arguments: [ "@security.authorization_checker" ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.view, method: onKernelView, priority: 70 }
```